# thymeleafで、数字の末尾の0を削除する方法

Tags: thymeleaf

実現したい実行結果としては、
　・10.0→10
　・10→10
　・1.01→1.01
　・1.20→1.2

現在は以下のstring.replaceで実現を試みているのですが、正規表現が使用出来ないようなので実現が難しそうです。

```html
th:text="${#strings.replace(value, text, text)}"
```

方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String型のままで実現したいという前提**であれば`custom expression`を作るのが現実的だと思います。

```
public final class MyStrings {
  public static String removeDecimalPointZero(String src) {
    // やりたいことを書く
  }
}
```

上記クラスを`myStrings`というexpression名で登録すれば以下のように使えます。

```
<span th:text="${#myStrings.removeDecimalPointZero(value)}">100</span>
```

`custom expression`の登録方法は`thymeleaf` 2.x/3.xで大きく異なる為、
使用しているバージョンに応じた方法を調べると良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとう御座います。参考にさせて頂きます。